# I want to make some script to run the curl command

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I'm trying to make some script to run the curl cmd.

`IP=$1
WEBPORT=$2
STREAMPORT=$3
NAME=$4`

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"
-d '{"Image": "kerberos/kerberos", "ExposedPorts": {
"80/tcp": {}, "8889/tcp": {} }, "HostConfig": {
"PortBindings": { "80/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "'+$WEBPORT+ '" }], 
"8889/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "'+$STREAMPORT+'" }] } } }'
 http://${IP}:4243/containers/create?name=${NAME}
```

It' is my script
But it's not working...
is there any way to run this curl cmd in the script and make this script more comfortable by making function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following code :

```
curl_post() {
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{'Image': 'kerberos/kerberos', 'ExposedPorts': { '80/tcp': {}, '8889/tcp': {} }, 'HostConfig': { 'PortBindings': { '80/tcp': [{ 'HostPort': '$1' }],'8889/tcp': [{ 'HostPort': '$2' }] } } }" "http://$3:4243/containers/create?name=$4"
}
```

To invoke the function do :

```
curl_post $webport $streamport $ip $name
```

It probably needs some modification, but i hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
But it has error i think this error is from server what i want to use.

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"Image": "kerberos/kerberos", "ExposedPorts": { "80/tcp": {}, "8889/tcp": {} }, "HostConfig": { "PortBindings": { "80/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "80" }], "8889/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "8889" }] } } }' http://10.0.2.15:4243/containers/create?name=camera

It is the whole CMD so is there any way to check is that same with the cmd you suggest

Comment: Oh i find the issue.
that is problem with ' and " after change eachother it's work very well Thank you curi0uz_k0d3r

It's really helpfull